# how to push and save an array (conserve the data of the array) inside node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to save the content of the array times for the next time the page is loaded. But when I reload the page the new content overwrites the old one. How could I go about doing that?

```
var times=[];


router.get('/log.html', function(req, res, next) {
    var time = new Date();
    times.push(time);
    res.send(times);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "new content overrides the old one"?  There is no new content here.  The array `times` has one item in it and that never changes in this code once the array is initially configured with that one item.

Comment: I realised that error, so I put the `var time = new Date();` and
`times.push(time);` inside the get function. But the array is still not expanding, when I refresh the page, I just receive a new date every time. @jfriend00

Comment: If that's what you want your question to be about, then use the "edit" link to fix your question so the code in your question shows what you want to ask about.   Putting that inside the route handler will cause a different value of `times` to be sent every time this route is hit (unless you're getting tricked by caching).

Comment: So, now (with the modified code) two consecutive hits to the `/log.html` route (without restarting the server) should give you successively more entries in the `times` array.  What problem are you seeing?

Comment: After sending a new get request I am getting the last new Date. It seems like array times is getting overwritten, I'm not sure. What I intend to have is for array times to expand and using the send method, print out all the dates which a user has requested a get method to this route.

Comment: There is nothing overwriting the `times` array unless you are restarting your server or your code is setting it somewhere else.  Are you running some tool that might be autorestarting your server?  Are you sure your real code is EXACTLY like what you show in the question and `times` is declared at the top level of the module and NOT inside the route handler?

Comment: I'm embraced to say I had a log.html file in my public folder that was overwriting the index.js methods. The problem is fixed now thanks.

Comment: One more question, I am getting "2021-04-06T06:14:47.152Z" as the output. Would you happen to know how to convert that into an unsorted list as the output? @jfriend00

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for in date formatting.  All the capabilities built-into the `Date` class are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  You can either use one of the other built-in formats or you can get the individual pieces you want from the Date object you have using its methods and then construct your own output format.

Comment: Also, what does "unsorted list" mean in this context?  Please show a precise example of the output you want.

Comment: All good, problem solved. thanks for the help